# WinRT API unable to get IDeviceIoControl

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winrt-async

I have taken base code for accessing custom driver through guid from osrfx2 sample.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Custom-device-access-sample-43bde679

I have tried to implement application in WinRT, which accesses the ndislwf filter driver

```
ComPtr<ICreateDeviceAccessAsync> access;    
ComPtr<IDeviceIoControl> deviceControl;

HRESULT hr = CreateDeviceAccessInstance(
    (PCWSTR)L"\\Device\\{5cbf81bd-5055-47cd-9055-a76b2b4e3697}",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    &access); // Returns S_OK.

hr = access->Wait(INFINITE);    // Returns S_OK.

hr = access->GetResult(IID_IDeviceIoControl,(void **)&deviceControl); // Returns E_INVALIDARGS.
```

I am unable to get the devicecontrol to send ioctl.

I mentioned guid in metadata file also.

Could anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, You may want to review the "[Access a custom driver](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Custom-device-access-sample-43bde679)" sample app.